# CodeIgniter - $this->uri->segment() returns empty

Tags: php, codeigniter, calendar

I am trying to get the [CodeIgniter calender library](https://ellislab.com/codeIgniter/user-guide/libraries/calendar.html) to work, and for that I need to use `$this->uri->segment()`, according to the documentation at least. The url for the calender looks like this:

> http://www.example.com/index.php/tasks/calendar/2015/03

Which means, as far as I can understand, that `$this->uri->segment(3`) would be the year, and `$this->uri->segment(4)` the month. However, both of these returns nothing at all, here is the code for my calender page:

```
echo "Selected year: ".$this->uri->segment(3)." and month: ".$this->uri->segment(4);
echo $this->calendar->generate($this->uri->segment(3), $this->uri->segment(4));
```

The first line is merely used for debugging purposes, and confirms that none of the commands returns any output. The calender library is loaded in the controller, with the following code:

```
public function calendar() {
    // Calender configuration (must be done prior to loading the library
    $conf = array(
            'start_day' => 'monday',
            'show_next_prev' => true,
            'next_prev_url' => base_url() . 'index.php/tasks/calendar'
    );

    // Load libraries and helpers
    $this->load->library('calendar',$conf);

    // Show page, including header and footer
    $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
    $this->load->view('tasks/calendar', $data);
    $this->load->view('templates/footer');
}
```

Can anyone tell me where I am failing? I read the documentation over and over again, and checked my code, but I can't see what I do different than their example?

**UPDATE**

I think I have ruled out that the problem is related to the `$this->uri->section()` function. Is likely to do with the controller loading an incorrect page, when additional sections is added to the URL after .../tasks/calendar/(...). I still haven't found a solution, but I wanted to let you know, in case others who read this had the same issue.

**UPDATE 2**

I think it might be a routing issue, the routes.php looks like this, for anything related to tasks:

```
$route['tasks/create']                  = 'tasks/create';
$route['tasks/calendar/(:num)/(:num)']  = 'tasks/calendar/$1/$2';
$route['tasks/calendar']                = 'tasks/calendar';
$route['tasks']                         = 'tasks';
$route['tasks/(:any)']                  = 'tasks/view/$1';
```

Comment: I decided to make a new issue, seeing as it isn't exactly the `$this->uri->segment()` which is the issue... If anyone is interested, it can be found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28765703/codeigniter-routing-issues-four-segments)

Answer (score 3):

for this to work you have to load the Codeigniter url helper since youre using `base_url()`. You can do this by running this `$this->load->helper('url');` or by going to your autoload.php and placing it there in `helper`

Comment: I have this line in my autoload.php:`$autoload['helper'] = array('url');`, shouldn't that work? Also tried adding it (the line you mentioned) in the controller, without any luck. Could it be my routing that is wrong?

Comment: this should be working for you.. it must be something else then. What do you get if you do this: `var_dump($this->uri->segment(1));` ?

Comment: That returns: string(5) - Which i believe is referring to "Task". I am beginning to think that it is actually not showing the calendar.php page, when the /[year]/[month] is in the url...

Comment: what does your `config.php` say for `base_url` and `index_page` ?

Comment: $config['index_page'] = 'index.php'; and $config['base_url'] = '';

Comment: so im assuming if you echo `$this->uri->segment(1)` you will get `tasks` correct?

Comment: so the problem is not you uri class, as that seems to be working fine.  is the code where youre echoing out the uris sitting inside `views\tasks\calendar.php` ?

Comment: Issue is likely not with the function. See update to the original post.

Comment: well if your URI reads `tasks/calendar/year/month` then in your controller you should be passing these variables like this `function calendar($year, $month){}` have you tried doing that?

Comment: another problem i see in your controller is that youre passing `$data` to your view, but `$data` is not defined

Answer (score 1):

Ok the problem here is not your URI class. The problem is that youre trying to use `$this->uri->segment()` inside your view. This is not how you should do this. You should only use that inside your controller. To fix this, you have two options, you can either pass your year and month as parameters to your controller method or you can use the uri->segment inside your controller.

- Example 1: Passing year and month as parameters

  URL: `index.php/tasks/calendar/2015/03`

  Controller:

  ```
  class Tasks extends MY_Controller {
      public function calendar($year, $month){
          $conf = array(
              'start_day' => 'monday',
              'show_next_prev' => true,
              'next_prev_url' => base_url() . 'index.php/tasks/calendar'
          );
          $this->load->library('calendar',$conf);
          $data = array(
              "year" => $year,
              "month" => $month
          );
          $this->load->view('tasks/calendar', $data);
      }
  }
  ```

  View:

  ```
  echo "Selected year: $year and month: $month";
  echo $this->calendar->generate($year, $month);
  ```
- Example 2: getting the variable using `$this->uri`

  URL: `index.php/tasks/calendar/2015/03`

  Controller:

  ```
  class Tasks extends MY_Controller {
      public function calendar(){
          $conf = array(
              'start_day' => 'monday',
              'show_next_prev' => true,
              'next_prev_url' => base_url() . 'index.php/tasks/calendar'
          );
          $this->load->library('calendar',$conf);
          $data = array(
              "year" => $this->uri->segment(3),
              "month" => $this->uri->segment(4)
          );
          $this->load->view('tasks/calendar', $data);
      }
  }
  ```

  View:

  ```
  echo "Selected year: $year and month: $month";
  echo $this->calendar->generate($year, $month);
  ```

Comment: Still doesn't work, but might very well be related to the routing, which I however dont understand (since I never had any issues with that). Added routes code in original post (update 2)

Comment: Please provide your routing information located in routes.php

Comment: Isn't that what I posted in "Update 2" in the original post? Or am I missing something?

Comment: yes this is what i was asking for. i will review it

Comment: if you want, ill be online for a while. I can help you debug it together, maybe remotely. let me know

Comment: Thanks for the offer, but that was in the middle of the night where I live :-). I will try to look everything over, to see if its something stupid (which it often is)

Comment: no problem, let me know if you need any help. im still here

Comment: Thanks. For now, all I have determined is that the issue is indeed that it does not show the calender page, but rather the index page for tasks. So it seems to be a routing issue...

Answer (score 0):

What do you get if you try echo

```
"Selected year: ".$this->uri->segment(1)." and month: ".$this->uri->segment(2);
```

I'm pretty sure the index is relative based on the `default_controller` path setting in the `routes.php` config.

Comment: Then the output is > Selected year: tasks and month: calendar